# Static import - Netbeans error

Tags: java, static, import

The error, Netbeans gives me, is:

> static import only from classes and interfaces

which is somehow strange for me, as this:

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
```

works fine while this:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
```

doesn't. Why is it not working for me?

BTW, GL11 is a class and I don't know why but Netbeans, when importing statically, thinks opengl is the class I want to import.

Comment: How's GL11 defined in the opengl class? It should be `public static final double GL11= ..`;

Comment: Well, GL11 is a class, actually.

Comment: Aah - that's the problem. GL11 is not a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanna write:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
```

You are importing the members of the class, thus the * at the end.

Comment: Or he can import constants under GL11.<some_constant> if he wants to get a particular one.

Comment: @CoolBeans to be more precise, he can import any accessible **static** members (fields, constants, methods).

Answer (score 1):

Static import allows you to import static fields of other class. For example you can say

`import static java.awt.Color.RED;`

And then use `RED` in your class without mentioning class where it is defined.